# EditTextPreference и стандартный вид

Tags: java, android, eclipse, activity

Доброго времени суток коллеги!

Есть такой вопрос. У меня есть активити, которое унаследовано от PreferenceActivity. В нем есть EditTextPreference. Я хочу, чтобы при клике на этот EditTextPreference открывался не стандартный диалог, типа этого:

[image]

а запускалась другая активити. Для этого я написал **OnPreferenceClickListener**, который запускается при клике на EditTextPreference, и вроде бы все хорошо - активити запускается. Но проблема в том, что вместе с ней запускается и старый диалог. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы этот диалог не показывался?

Answer (score 1):

Так тогда зачем тебе обязательно `EditTextPreference`?

Воспользуйся другим классом и на него слушателя назначай.